# how to trigger an event after component did mount with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When a user clicks a button, a component is supposed to be mounted, once the component is mounted, `window.print()` is supposed to be run and then the component is supposed to be unmounted again.

With component lifecycles this was easy but with hooks I am not sure how to solve this.

```
export default function App() {
  const [showCmp, setShowCmp] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowCmp(true);

    window.print();

    setShowCmp(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {showCmp && <Cmp1 />}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using `useEffect` but it didn't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (showCmp) window.print();
}, [showCmp]);
```

here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-shape-t9l0f?file=/src/App.js)

how do I determine when the component is mounted correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you worried if the component mounted "correctly"? Which component? A component is either mounted, or not. This is how React works.

Comment: my reason is that the component has a very large image and takes a while to load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Be sure to also provide the code for `<Cmp1 />` :)

### Analysis

Looking at your Code Sandbox, you have:

**Cmp1.js**

```js
import React from "react";

const Cmp1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      This is my Component{" "}
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Very_Large_Array%2C_2012.jpg" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cmp1;
```

Based on this, it seems like your question is not "how can I trigger an event after a component *mounts*?" but instead "how can I trigger an event after a resource ***loads***?"

This is an important distinction because the time at which React finishes **rendering** does not equal the time at which an image has finished **loading**.

You can use the `onLoad` handler for `<img>` which is invoked when the image has finished loading (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) for more info on the `onload` event handler).

### Solution

1. Modify `Cmp1` to accept an `onLoad` prop:

   ```js
   import React from "react";

   const Cmp1 = (props) => {
     return (
       <div>
         This is my Component{" "}
         <img
           src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Very_Large_Array%2C_2012.jpg"
           alt="The 'Very Large Array' observatory"
           onLoad={props.onLoad}
         />
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default Cmp1;
   ```
2. Create an `onLoad` handler in the parent component which calls `window.print()` and pass it down to `<Cmp1>`:

   ```js
   import React, { useState } from "react";

   import Cmp1 from "./Cmp1";

   import "./styles.css";

   export default function App() {
     const [showCmp, setShowCmp] = useState(false);

     const handleClick = () => {
       setShowCmp(true);
     };

     const onLoad = () => {
       // Wait until the image loads to print
       window.print();

       // Hide the component after printing
       setShowCmp(false);
     };

     return (
       <div className="App">
         <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
         <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

         {/* Pass the `onLoad` callback down to the child */}
         {showCmp && <Cmp1 onLoad={onLoad} />}
         <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
3. Now, the browser will not call `print()` until the image is loaded.

   [image: Example of printing after image loads]

[image: Edit epic-jennings-kj7g2]

### Other Notes

In the event that your image fails to load, you can use the `onError` React event handler in the `<img>` component. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) for more info on the `onerror` event handler.

Comment: ahhh thanks! And thanks for all the tips !

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply wanting to mount the child component, print the screen, and then unmount it you can do all this in a `useEffect` hook.

## Issues

Basically you can't enqueue cancelling state updates within a single render cycle, i.e.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  setShowCmp(true);
  window.print();
  setShowCmp(false);
};
```

Would enqueue the `true` state update, print the screen (without the child mounted), and enqueue the `false` state update, the net effect being state isn't really updated and you printed the screen without the child.

## Solution

By splitting up the state updates you can fit a print screen between them.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (showCmp) { // <-- (2a) if true, then...
    window.print(); // <-- (3) print screen
    setShowCmp(false); // <-- (4) toggle back false
  }
}, [showCmp]);

const handleClick = () => {
  setShowCmp(true); // <-- (1) toggle true to trigger effect
};

...

{showCmp && <Cmp1 />} // <-- (2b) if true, mount and render component
```

Child component

If you simply want to know when a component has mounted, use an `useEffect` with empty dependency array.

```
const Cmp1 = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Mounted!!');
  }, [])
  return <div>This is my Component</div>;
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-trigger-an-event-after-component-did-mount-with-react-hooks]

Comment: this does not work if the component has a very large image and takes time to load, I forked your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-component-did-mount-with-react-hooks-forked-ihpdy?file=/src/Cmp1.js

Comment: @Tom Sure, if the mounting component has to do a lot of work when it mounts it can take a bit of time. What you may try then is to put the `setShowCmp(false);` in a `setTimeout` to toggle it off in a second or two, or pass a callback to the child to notify the parent when it as fully loaded, i.e. use an `onLoad` event handler on the large slow-loading images.